# “No such method error” when using android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getActionBar

Tags: android, fragment, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying navigation drawer in gingerbread everything working fine.When I click on navigation menu I am getting this exception.I added everything library,theme,drawer list. Actually I need getsupportActionBar() in fragment so how can I get it please help me.

code:

```
public class RiverFragment extends Fragment{


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Retrieving the currently selected item number
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");

        // List of rivers
        String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

        // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        // Getting reference to the TextView of the Fragment
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

        // Setting currently selected river name in the TextView
        tv.setText(rivers[position]);       

        // Updating the action bar title
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(rivers[position]);


        return v;
    }
}
```

exception:

```
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getActionBar
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.navigationdrawerdemo.RiverFragment.onCreateView(RiverFragment.java:36)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-04 11:47:21.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20537):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which library you have added into your application project?

Comment: android-support-v7-appcompat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried this code it is working fine

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(rivers[position]);
```

Comment: But my compiler doesnt recognize ActionBarActivity ??

Comment: add appcompat library to your application

Comment: I have not used **Actionbar Sherlock** and looking for alternative and got this solution working for me.

Answer (score 11):

Your activity must extend [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) instead of `FragmentActivity` (note that `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` - it just adds support for the action bar via `getSupportActionBar()`).

Answer (score 1):

You should add actionbarsherlock library [Actionbar Sherlock for android](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html)

then `extends` your fragment with `SherlockFragment`
then you can take

```
getActivity().getSupportActionbar().setTitle("");
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: Cannot use Actionbar Sherlock already have errors when imported in eclipse .